# getTag, setTag checkbox issue, how can I get my activity to post checked boxes? The other values are posting ok

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am in the process of changing someone else's code from `listView` to `recyclerView`, changing code in my `activity` and my `adapter` where required - the `adapter` is a big change, with `OnCreateView`, `onBindViewHolder` and so on...

As the question indicates, `category`, `name`, `phone`, `address`, `comment`, `public_or_private` are posting successfully to `mySql db`, but nothing for `checkedContacts`. I'd be very grateful if you could tell me how to fix the problem.

I am quite sure it has to do with something around this line:

```
//get the other data related to the selected contact - name and number
SelectPhoneContact contact = (SelectPhoneContact) checkbox.getTag();
```

I am not getting any errors but when I run in debug mode it gets to here and then jumps to:

```
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("there's a problem here unfortunately");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I think it has something to do with `setTag` but I find it confusing and I'm not sure where it should be set (if, even, that is the problem).

I'm posting the relevant code for my activity, `NewContact` and the RecyclerViewAdapter, `PopulistoCOntactsAdapter`. Thanks for any help.

```
NewContact.java

    //for the SAVE button
    private void saveContactButton() {

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("you clicked it, save");

                try {
                    System.out.println("we're in the try part");

                    int count = MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size();

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                        //for each Matching Contacts row in the listview
                        LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)recyclerView.getChildAt(i); // Find by under LinearLayout

                        //for each Matching Contacts checkbox in the listview
                        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);

                        //get the other data related to the selected contact - name and number
                        SelectPhoneContact contact = (SelectPhoneContact) checkbox.getTag();

                        //if that checkbox is checked, then get the phone number
                        if(checkbox.isChecked()) {
                            Log.d("Item " + String.valueOf(i), checkbox.getTag().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(NewContact.this, contact.getPhone(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            // make each checked contact in selectPhoneContacts
                            // into an individual
                            // JSON object called checkedContact
                            JSONObject checkedContact = new JSONObject();

                            // checkedContact will be of the form {"checkedContact":"+353123456"}
                            checkedContact.put("checkedContact", contact.getPhone());

                            // Add checkedContact JSON Object to checkedContacts jsonArray
                            //The JSON Array will be of the form
                            // [{"checkedContact":"+3531234567"},{"checkedContact":"+353868132813"}]
                            //we will be posting this JSON Array to Php, further down below
                            checkedContacts.put(checkedContact);
                            System.out.println("NewContact: checkedcontact JSONObject :" + checkedContact);
                        }

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("there's a problem here unfortunately");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                //When the user clicks save
                //post phoneNoofUserCheck to NewContact.php and from that
                //get the user_id in the user table, then post category, name, phone etc...
                //to the review table
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, NewContact_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                //response, this will show the checked numbers being posted
                                Toast.makeText(NewContact.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }

                        }) {

                    //post these details to the NewContact.php file and do
                    //stuff with it
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        //post the phone number to php to get the user_id in the user table
                        params.put("phonenumberofuser", phoneNoofUserCheck);
                        //the second value, categoryname.getText().toString() etc...
                        // is the value we get from Android.
                        //the key is "category", "name" etc.
                        // When we see these in our php,  $_POST["category"],
                        //put in the value from Android
                        params.put("category", categoryname.getText().toString());
                        params.put("name", namename.getText().toString());
                        params.put("phone", phonename.getText().toString());
                        params.put("address", addressname.getText().toString());
                        params.put("comment", commentname.getText().toString());

                        params.put("public_or_private", String.valueOf(public_or_private));
                        System.out.println("public_or_private is " + String.valueOf(public_or_private));

                        //this is the JSON Array of checked contacts
                        //it will be of the form
                        //[{"checkedContact":"+3531234567"},{"checkedContact":"+353868132813"}]
                        params.put("checkedContacts", checkedContacts.toString());

                        return params;

                    }


                };


                // Adding request to request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

                //when saved, go back to the PopulistoListView class and update with
                //the new entry
                Intent j = new Intent(NewContact.this, PopulistoListView.class);
                j.putExtra("phonenumberofuser", phoneNoofUserCheck);

                NewContact.this.startActivity(j);

                finish();

            }

        });

}

}
```

---

```
PopulistoContactsAdapter.java

public class PopulistoContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    //make a List containing info about SelectPhoneContact objects
    public List<SelectPhoneContact> theContactsList;

    Context context_type;

    public class MatchingContact extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //In each recycler_blueprint show the items you want to have appearing
        public TextView title, phone;
        public CheckBox check;
        public Button invite;

        public MatchingContact(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //title is cast to the name id, in recycler_blueprint,
            //phone is cast to the id called no etc
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
            invite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);
            check = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);

        }

    }

    public class nonMatchingContact extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //In each recycler_blueprint show the items you want to have appearing
        public TextView title, phone;
        public CheckBox check;
        public Button invite;


        public nonMatchingContact(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //title is cast to the name id, in recycler_blueprint,
            //phone is cast to the id called no etc
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
            invite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);
            check = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //for each row in recyclerview, get the getType_row, set in NewContact.java
        return Integer.parseInt(theContactsList.get(position).getType_row());
    }


    public PopulistoContactsAdapter(List<SelectPhoneContact> selectPhoneContacts, Context context) {
        //selectPhoneContacts = new ArrayList<SelectPhoneContact>();

        theContactsList = selectPhoneContacts;
       // whichactivity = activity;
        context_type = context;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView;

        //if getType_row is 1...
        if (viewType == 1)

        {

            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_blueprint, parent, false);

            //itemView.setTag();
            return new MatchingContact(itemView);

        } else {

            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_blueprint_non_matching, parent, false);

            return new nonMatchingContact(itemView);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        //bind the views into the ViewHolder
        //selectPhoneContact is an instance of the SelectPhoneContact class.
        //We will assign each row of the recyclerview to contain details of selectPhoneContact:

        //The number of rows will match the number of phone contacts
        final SelectPhoneContact selectPhoneContact = theContactsList.get(position);

        if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == 1)

        {

            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());


            CheckBox check = ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check;

            //get the number position of the checkbox in the recyclerview
            //check.setTag(position);

            }


         else {

            ((nonMatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
            ((nonMatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());

        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return theContactsList.size();
    }
}
```

And here is my `SelectPhoneContact` class:

```
public class SelectPhoneContact {

    String phone;

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    boolean isMatching;

    public boolean isMatching(){return isMatching;}

    public void setIsMatchingContact(boolean isMatching){

        this.isMatching = isMatching;

    }



    //*****************************************
    //this is for the checkbox
    boolean selected = false;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected){

            this.selected = selected;

    }


    String type_row;

    public String getType_row() {
        return type_row;
    }

    public void setType_row(String type_row) {
        this.type_row = type_row;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This tutorial was very helpful: https://demonuts.com/2017/07/03/recyclerview-checkbox-android/

Here is the code I used for `NewContact.java:`

```
 //for the SAVE button
    private void saveContactButton() {

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("you clicked it, save");

                try {
                    System.out.println("we're in the try part");

                    //loop through the matching contacts
                    int count = MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size();

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                        //for matching contacts that are checked...
                        if (PopulistoContactsAdapter.theContactsList.get(i).getSelected()) {
                            Toast.makeText(NewContact.this, PopulistoContactsAdapter.theContactsList.get(i).getPhone() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // make each checked contact in selectPhoneContacts
                            // into an individual
                            // JSON object called checkedContact
                            JSONObject checkedContact = new JSONObject();

                            // checkedContact will be of the form {"checkedContact":"+353123456"}
                            checkedContact.put("checkedContact", PopulistoContactsAdapter.theContactsList.get(i).getPhone());

                            // Add checkedContact JSON Object to checkedContacts jsonArray
                            //The JSON Array will be of the form
                            // [{"checkedContact":"+3531234567"},{"checkedContact":"+353868132813"}]
                            //we will be posting this JSON Array to Php, further down below
                            checkedContacts.put(checkedContact);
                            System.out.println("NewContact: checkedcontact JSONObject :" + checkedContact);
                        }

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("there's a problem here unfortunately");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                //When the user clicks save
                //post phoneNoofUserCheck to NewContact.php and from that
                //get the user_id in the user table, then post category, name, phone etc...
                //to the review table
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, NewContact_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                //response, this will show the checked numbers being posted
                                Toast.makeText(NewContact.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }

                        }) {

                    //post these details to the NewContact.php file and do
                    //stuff with it
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        //post the phone number to php to get the user_id in the user table
                        params.put("phonenumberofuser", phoneNoofUserCheck);
                        //the second value, categoryname.getText().toString() etc...
                        // is the value we get from Android.
                        //the key is "category", "name" etc.
                        // When we see these in our php,  $_POST["category"],
                        //put in the value from Android
                        params.put("category", categoryname.getText().toString());
                        params.put("name", namename.getText().toString());
                        params.put("phone", phonename.getText().toString());
                        params.put("address", addressname.getText().toString());
                        params.put("comment", commentname.getText().toString());

                        params.put("public_or_private", String.valueOf(public_or_private));
                        System.out.println("public_or_private is " + String.valueOf(public_or_private));

                        //this is the JSON Array of checked contacts
                        //it will be of the form
                        //[{"checkedContact":"+3531234567"},{"checkedContact":"+353868132813"}]
                        params.put("checkedContacts", checkedContacts.toString());

                        return params;

                    }


                };


                // Adding request to request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

                //when saved, go back to the PopulistoListView class and update with
                //the new entry
                Intent j = new Intent(NewContact.this, PopulistoListView.class);
                j.putExtra("phonenumberofuser", phoneNoofUserCheck);

                NewContact.this.startActivity(j);

                finish();

            }

        });


    }
}
```

And my `PopulistoContactsAdapter.java:`

```
public class PopulistoContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    //make a List containing info about SelectPhoneContact objects
    public static List<SelectPhoneContact> theContactsList;

    Context context_type;

    public class MatchingContact extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //In each recycler_blueprint show the items you want to have appearing
        public TextView title, phone;
        public CheckBox check;
        public Button invite;

        public MatchingContact(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //title is cast to the name id, in recycler_blueprint,
            //phone is cast to the id called no etc
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
            invite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);
            check = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);

        }

    }

    public class nonMatchingContact extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //In each recycler_blueprint show the items you want to have appearing
        public TextView title, phone;
        public CheckBox check;
        public Button invite;


        public nonMatchingContact(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //title is cast to the name id, in recycler_blueprint,
            //phone is cast to the id called no etc
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
            invite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInvite);
            check = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //for each row in recyclerview, get the getType_row, set in NewContact.java
        return Integer.parseInt(theContactsList.get(position).getType_row());
    }


    public PopulistoContactsAdapter(List<SelectPhoneContact> selectPhoneContacts, Context context) {
        //selectPhoneContacts = new ArrayList<SelectPhoneContact>();

        theContactsList = selectPhoneContacts;
       // whichactivity = activity;
        context_type = context;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView;

        //if getType_row is 1...
        if (viewType == 1)

        {

            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_blueprint, parent, false);

            //itemView.setTag();
            return new MatchingContact(itemView);

        } else {

            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_blueprint_non_matching, parent, false);

            return new nonMatchingContact(itemView);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        //bind the views into the ViewHolder
        //selectPhoneContact is an instance of the SelectPhoneContact class.
        //We will assign each row of the recyclerview to contain details of selectPhoneContact:

        //The number of rows will match the number of phone contacts
        final SelectPhoneContact selectPhoneContact = theContactsList.get(position);

        if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == 1)

        {

            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setText("Cheeckbox" + position);
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(theContactsList.get(position).getSelected());
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setTag(position);

            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Integer pos = (Integer) ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (theContactsList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                        theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                    } else {
                        theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                    }
                }
            });
           // CheckBox check = ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check;

            //get the number position of the checkbox in the recyclerview
            //check.setTag(position);

            }


         else {

            ((nonMatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
            ((nonMatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());

        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return theContactsList.size();
    }
}
```